# How I can get data from a Olap Cube in Excel C# Addin

Tags: c#, ssas, olap, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I have an SSAS 2012 cube and I need create an excel addin for get data from cube and show it in a pivot table.

What code I need for create pivot table with connection to olap cube.

Comment: There is an open source project named "OLAP Pivot Table Extensions" which extends the existing Excel Pivot table functionality. I never looked into the source code, but maybe you can find some useful ideas in it. You can find the project at http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/

Comment: Why bother? Excel can connect to an SSAS cube and expose the data as a Pivot Table.  The interface is pretty good in Excel 2010 or 2013 - it would take you years of coding to even come close.  There are also Excel Cube Formulas if you just want data into a single cell.

Comment: but I need create pivot table with C# Code

Answer (score -1):

There are several tools and APIs to connect from C# to an OLAP cube. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP#APIs_and_query_languages) are some examples, I personally used [OLE DB for OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB_for_OLAP) which was useful for connecting to the cube and querying with MDX; I built up the queries based on the options chosen by the users from the form.

Comment: The answer is somewhat helpful to point a user in the right direction, but the resources provided dont really help the user get started on a solution.